# NSString search for character from the location of the cursor in a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am stuck with trying to figure out how I can find the occurrence of a character from a specified range (i.e. the current position of the cursor).

I know how to find the current position of the cursor using

```
NSRange cursorPosition = [textView.text selectedRange];
```

But I am trying to figure out how I can search backward from `cursorPosition`.

What I am trying to do is, for example, if I have a string:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello I am tagging @xyz to notify them of the tag"
```

Suppose in `string`, the location of the cursor is just before `"to"`, I want to search from the location of the cursor to the location of `@` in the string and take the substring from the `cursorPosition` to `@`.

Please let me know if my description is vague or not well written, I will explain it further.

Any help would be great! Thanks a lot!

Edit: Thanks a lot for all your time and responses!

Comment: i see yesterday i did such, please wait a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `rangeOfString:options:range:`.

```
// Get the current selection range
NSRange cursorPosition = [textView.text selectedRange];
if (cursorPosition.location != NSNotFound) {
    // Build range from start of text up to the start of the selection
    NSRange searchRange = NSRangeMake(0, cursorPosition.location);
    // Find the desired substring within the range
    NSRange matchRange = [textView.text rangeOfString:@"@" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:searchRange];
    if (matchRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        // Build range starting with the found substring up to the start of the selection
        NSRange textRange = NSRangeMake(matchRange.location, searchRange.length - matchRange.location);
        // Get the text in the desired range
        NSString *matchingText = [textView.text substringInRange:textRange];
        NSLog(@"Matching text to caret is %@", matchingText);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No match up to the caret");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"No selection");
}
```

Note that this code looks up to the start of any current selection in the text view. If you want to search within the current selection you will need to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSRange cursorPosition = [textView.text selectedRange];
NSString *string = @"Hello I am tagging @xyz to notify them of the tag";
    NSInteger loc = [string rangeOfString : @"@"].location;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(loc, (cursorPosition.location - loc));
    NSString *newString = [string substringWithRange: range];
```

Comment: What if the `@` is after the cursor position? BTW - do not use `int`, use `NSInteger`.

Comment: `loc` should be `NSInteger`, not `NSInteger *`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger cursorPosition = [_textView selectedRange].location;

NSInteger stringPosition = [_textView.text rangeOfString:@"@"].location;

if (stringPosition < cursorPosition) {
    stringPosition = stringPosition + 1;
}

NSInteger lengthFinal = labs(cursorPosition - stringPosition);
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(MIN(cursorPosition, stringPosition), lengthFinal);

NSString *finalSubString = [_textView.text substringWithRange:range];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. **Place cursor and enter back button to test**

```
-(BOOL)textView:(nonnull UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(nonnull NSString *)text{

NSRange rangeFrom = [textView.text rangeOfString:@"@"];
NSString *result = [textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeFrom.location+1, range.location-rangeFrom.location)];
NSLog(@"result:%@",result);//result:xyz


return YES;
}
```

// ...........************ check with this....Why not is this working....*/

```
NSRange cursorPosition = NSMakeRange(23, 1);//[textView.text range];//selectedRange
NSString *string = @"Hello I am tagging @xyz to notify them of the tag";
NSRange rangeFrom = [string rangeOfString:@"@"];
NSString *result = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeFrom.location+1, cursorPosition.location-rangeFrom.location)];
NSLog(@"result:%@",result);//result:xyz
```

Comment: 1. The question is about `UITextView`. 2. It has nothing to do with changing characters in the text view. 3. Your posted code won't even compile.